# Active Record Outer Left Join on ElasticSearch Results (Rails 4.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord, elasticsearch

I use a scope on a model that does an outer left join to consolidate SQL queries. I'd like to use ElasticSearch to query this model, but I can't figure out how to get the join to play nice with ES.

When I try to add it as a scope or add the join manually to the ES search results, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /families/search
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: ...NT(families.*, COALESCE(SUM(donations.amount), 0) AS total_r...
                                                         ^
: SELECT  COUNT(families.*, COALESCE(SUM(donations.amount), 0) AS total_raised) AS count_families_all_coalesce_sum_donations_amount_0_as_total_rai, families.id AS families_id FROM "families" LEFT OUTER JOIN donations ON families.id = donations.recipient_id WHERE "families"."id" = 56 GROUP BY families.id LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

Here is my model:

```
# app/models/family.rb

require 'elasticsearch/model'
require 'file_size_validator'

class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  has_many :donations, as: :recipient, dependent: :destroy

  scope :approved, -> { where(approved: true).order('families.created_at DESC') }
  scope :unapproved, -> { where approved: false }

  scope :visible, -> { where(visible: true).order('families.created_at DESC') }
  scope :hidden, -> { where(visible: false) }

  scope :include_total_raised, -> { joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN donations ON families.id = donations.recipient_id').select('families.*, COALESCE(SUM(donations.amount), 0) AS total_raised').group('families.id') }
```

Here is my controller that is doing the searching:

```
class FamiliesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_family, only: [:edit, :show, :update, :approval_letter]

  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :require_login, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :approval_letter]

  def index
    @families = Family.approved.visible.include_total_raised.select(:id, :photo, :first_name, :last_name, :country, :slug).order('families.created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(30)
  end

  def search
    if params[:q].present?
      @families = Family.approved.visible.search(params[:q]).records.include_total_raised.page(params[:page]).per(30)
      render :index
    else
      redirect_to families_path
    end
  end
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a problem w/ my HAML template:

```
%h2= pluralize(@families.length, 'Adopting family')
```

That line is trying to `count` the `@families` ivar which caused some issues w/ Kaminari & the join. When I commented out that line it worked great, but I still wanted to show how many search results were found. So I just changed `count` to `length` and it worked great.